# How to deal with spam

Tags: discussion

Since the traffic on Korean Beta SE is so small, the number of spam is not that big. However, we don't have a moderator appointed yet and I've just found that my spam flag aged away without being taken care of. **We have to take care of them on our own until moderators are nominated.** And we have to keep flagging them even if we have moderators.

1. When you see a post like [Is there any equivalent proverb for "Slow and steady wins the race"?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/is-there-any-equivalent-proverb-for-slow-and-steady-wins-the-race/1707#1707), please flag it as spam.
2. When you see a post like the below image, please flag it as "rude or abusive (offensive)".

[image]

When you flag a post as either of them, it will be automatically downvoted. You don't have to worry about losing one reputation point when flagging an answer.

> - 3 flags on a question (spam or rude or abusive): question is banished from the front page and all question lists except search
>     results.
> - 6 flags (spam or rude or abusive): post is locked, deleted, and the author loses 100 reputation.

For more information, please read Meta SE question, [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)

**Please do not edit those posts**:

> Stack Exchange has an algorithm that automatically learns which posts
>   are flagged as spam and tries to block those, and editing the spam can
>   decrease the efficacy of the filter.

**Edit**: 
[Expressing "from A to B" in a more concise way](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/expressing-a-to-b/1720#1720) (another spam from the same user name who posted the spam above-linked)

I have just noticed that **3 flags on a question (spam or rude or abusive): question is banished from the front page** is not happening. I guess it is because Korea SE is beta. I will update it when I find the reason.

Comment: Another spam. http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/expressing-a-to-b/1720#1720

Answer (score 1):

As we have three moderators now who can single-handedly delete spam and rude or offensive posts, we might not need 6 flags to delete them. But, please continue to flag them when you find them.

You can get a [**bronze** citizen patrol badge](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) for your first flag, a [**silver** duputy badge](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy) when you raise 80 helpful flags, and a [**gold** marshall badge](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal) when you raise 500  helpful flags.

**Flagging helps the community to clean up the mess.**